# j2me polish PIM List

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish, jsr75

I have made an app for j2me Mobile, now I wanted to give it polish effects for which I copied Build.xml and resources folder and the issues were solved, but my project uses `javax.microedition.pim.Contact;` and I have written my whole code using that API.

When I clean & debug this project it gives error as below

```
error: package javax.microedition.pim does not exist
import javax.microedition.pim.Contact;  //if it asks to import then there should be a way, but what?
```

I know polish offers its own PIM API as `de.enough.polish.pim.PimContact`, but I can't change my code for this. What I want to do is to apply polish css effects and run it as polish project but using the `javax.microedition.pim.Contact` for PIM operations.

There should be some way to use it and I guess there is, I did try to find something useful there but couldn't get it. I am new to polish and J2me so there is possibility of lack of knowledge. But I would love to find a satisfactory answer to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange that being so many users and developers of J2me and Nokia I didn't get the answer of a stupid mistake I was doing since long. I just had to select the PIM api from the selection of target API and devices when creating the object as we know that in all J2me or Nokia uses the Generic `javax.microedition.PIM api`. Sorry for answering my own question but I think it could be helpful for any other dumb like me. Thanks for bearing